# Extending an interface in a class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have question that is more or less technical. I would like to do the following:

Have a class that will define both a default constructor and another constructor that will create a new object called NamedRunnable.

This class will effectively implement the Runnable interface thus including the run method that it provides.

I want to find a way to no explicitly implement the run method within the the 'NamedRunnable' class itself but have it implemented within all member that will subclass the said class.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you want to achieve: You want a contructor which takes a Runnable and the the run-method to run this Runnable?

Comment: can you show us psuedo-code , I really don't understand what you want

Comment: Do you want this? 
public class NamedRunnable implements Runnable {.. public void run(){}}
It is certainly possible

Comment: *"in to be able to get the functionality (the .run()) method with not much effort..."* Implementing `Runnable` is trivially easy, there's *already* not much effort involved.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you meant, then yes it is possible :)

```
public class NamedRunnable implements Runnable {
    public NamedRunnable(String name) {
        // ....
    }

    public void run() {
        // ...,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as mentioned in the original question, this is what I wanted to avoid. Instead I defined the new class as abstract and had each class that subclassed it, implement the run method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an *abstract class* (can't be instantiated) that implements `Runnable`:

```
abstract class NamedRunnable implements Runnable {
    private String name;

    protected NamedRunnable(String _name) {
        this.name = _name;
    }
}
```

Note that that doesn't implement `run`. `run` is implicitly abstract in that class, as though you had included

```
abstract public void run();
```

...because we declare the interface but don't implement it (which we wouldn't be allowed to do if the class weren't declared `abtract`).

You'd use that as a base class for a concrete class, e.g.:

```
class Thingy extends NamedRunnable {
    public Thingy(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The concrete class has the `run` implementation, and can be instantiated.

Comment: You don't even need to define run in NamedRunnable as it is implicit

Comment: I was meaning to post an answer, as I did exactly what you said before seeing the actual response but with a minor difference which was to declare the method run() as an abstract method within my abstract class.

Comment: @Aris: Originally I did too, but as Nicolas pointed out above, there's no need, it's implicit. The end result is the same with or without having `abstract public void run();` explicitly typed inside `NamedRunnable`.